# HTTP links do not open in Firefox

Tags: windows, windows-8, firefox, http, links

There's a GIF of some program on Windows 8 (e.g. Nvidia settings window where you can click Download button to go to web and download latest driver)

[image]

So nothing happens when clicked, the window just blinks. This happens to all programs I have, including Mozilla Thunderbird, Skype, even not programs e.g. Control Panel.

- I tried disabling security (only Malwarebytes and Windows firewall)
- I tried clean boot
- I tried safe mode
- I scanned my computer from viruses
- I ran sfc /scannow and various dism commands
- I ran Tweaking.com Windows Repair repair package in safe mode
- No errors in Event Viewer
- I do use CCleaner to clean and fix registry
- Internet browsers like Firefox, Chrome and IE does work and open links when browsing pages, but it doesn't open any browser when clicking on a link on a non-browser program.
- I checked my default programs set to open HTTP/HTTPs, Firefox is set to it.

I'm on win8x64 (not 8.1)

EDIT: Fun fact, so far I found only one program that opens links and it's mIRC software for IRC chatting. However at the same time other IRC software like XChat does not work.

EDIT2: Okay, narrowed down the issue. In the default programs settings I switched all links to open by default by Google Chrome from Firefox and it worked, links did open. Then I set it all back to Firefox and it doesn't work again. So it got to be Firefox issue. Firefox is my primary browser, I cannot stick with Chrome just because of this issue.

- I did clean uninstall and delete all folders in %APPDATA% and fresh install Firefox, didn't solve.

Comment: I wonder if the path it has stored for Firefox is somehow incorrect? Is there an option to specifically select firefox.exe via some dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a registry issue and you may have to dig too deep to get it done.

> I do use CCleaner to clean and fix registry

Registry cleaners often have unwanted results, and that may be the case here. You should often back-up your registry if you go down this way.

However, there's a possible workaround if you want to stick with Firefox (and stick you should!) in that you can use the developer edition instead: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

If you'd rather the UI of the regular Firefox, there's an option in about:settings